# Git: squash all then "extract" some commits

Tags: git

My git commits are a bit messed up and I was wondering if I could squash them all together and then "extract" some commits from that commit.

Let's say I have these files in one commit:
upload.py,
moderate.py,
upload.html,
moderaion.html

How can I split it in two commits like this?
upload:
upload.py,
upload.html

moderation:
moderate.py,
moderaion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question implies that the commits are already messy, but if the commits themselves are 'atomic' but just in the wrong order, you can also use [git rebase --interactive](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) to put them in the right order and then squash them. This might make things more easy for you.

If the commits already touch several areas and you want to split them up, again, [git rebase -i](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_splitting_commits) can help. Also have a look at the example at [Bart's blog](http://www.jukie.net/~bart/blog/20081112150409).

Comment: The blog had all the answers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First you can squash all the commits together with `git rebase --interactive X` (where X is the parent of the commits you want to squash). After that run `git rebase --interactive X` a second time, but now split the squashed commit as described in [git-rebase's manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_splitting_commits).

Before you start rebasing, it's best to mark down the current head commit. Write down its hash or create a new tag/branch. That way you can easily revert all your changes and try again.

Comment: No need for tagging or writing down hash now that there is reflog on by default (HEAD@{1}, @{1}, etc.)

Comment: True. But it's easier when you don't need to figure out whether it was @{1}, @{2} or something else after making lots of operations that modify the head.